# Laravel 5.4 $this->validate error handling in the controller

Tags: laravel

I have an app in **Laravel 5.4**. Now i want to validate a request but also handling the errors in the controller. Now it redirects back and i don't want that.

How can i achieve that in Laravel 5.4?

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|max:1000|mimes:jpg',
    ]);

    if(**errors**){
        // do this
        abort(Response::HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);//example
    }else{
        //do that
        abort(Response::HTTP_OK);//example

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->validate()` validate user inputs and returns previous page with errors stored in `$errors` variable.

You can use `Validator::make()` which can validate user inputs but don't return previous page.

So something like this:

```
// Create validation
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
    array('file' => 'required|max:1000|mimes:jpg')
);

// Check validation
if ($validator->fails())
{
    // The given data did not pass validation
}
```

Taken from Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: Very strange, i did tried that and it didn't work, now it works! Thnx!